# using Enumeration<E> 's hasMoreElements() and nextElement() method to print a list, succeeded 1st time, failed 2nd time after adding some element

Tags: java, enumeration

I'm new to Java and is trying to learn the Enumeration 's hasMoreElements() and nextElement() method. After I added some elements to the `p1` list while deleted others from the `p1` list, I tried to print everything, however, it failed to do so? Why is this happening?

```
Properties p1 = new Properties();

try (OutputStream os1  = new FileOutputStream("xanadu123.properties")) {

    //set the properties value
    p1.setProperty("database", "localhost");
    p1.setProperty("1", "one");
    p1.setProperty("2", "two");

} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

Enumeration<Object> eString1 = p1.elements();
while (eString1.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(eString1.nextElement());
}

System.out.println("after printing eString1");

p1.setProperty("3", "three");
p1.remove("2");

System.out.println("before printing eString1 again");

while (eString1.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(eString1.nextElement());
}
```

Output:

```
two
one
localhost
after printing eString1
before printing eString1 again
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic answer is that you cannot rely on `Enumeration` working if you modify the thing you're enumerating (in this case, the `Properties`).  Once you do that, the `Enumeration` you constructed may no longer work.

The newer version of `Enumeration`, `Iterator`, is the same way, with the exception that *some* `Iterator`s provide a `remove` method that allows you to remove the "current element" from a collection without breaking the iterator.  (But you have to use the `remove` method of the `Iterator`; you can't use any other mechanism for removing an element, or else you could break the iterator.)

The basic reason is that an `Enumeration` or `Iterator` contains state information about the entity you're enumerating.  If you modify that entity, the state information may no longer be valid.  Suppose, for example, that you're iterating over an `ArrayList`.  Most likely, the iterator will contain an integer that's the "current" index of the array.  If you then insert something at the front of the `ArrayList`, the element that is pointed to by that index will become a different element, and next time you call `next` on the iterator, it will look at the element at that index and return the same element it returned last time.  In your case, I'd guess that one piece of state information kept in the `Enumeration` is a `boolean` instance variable that says, "Have I reached the end yet?"  Once you reach the end of the `Properties`, that variable will become `true`.  If you then add more properties, the "end-of-the-enumeration" variable will still be true, even though it's effectively wrong at this point.

It simply isn't practical to try to set up `Enumerators` and `Iterators` so that they adjust themselves whenever the underlying entity changes.  Either a `Properties` object (or an `ArrayList` or whatever) would need to keep track of every `Enumerator` or `Iterator` created from it, and then go find all of them and adjust them whenever something is done that changes the `Properties`; or else each `Enumerator` or `Iterator` would need a way to query the `Properties` to ask it, what changes have happened since the last time I checked?  Either of those would be very complicated.  Consider also that `Properties` is a hash table, so that when you add a new element, you could add it to any bucket in the hash table.  If the `Enumerator` has already scanned over that bucket, how would it know to go back and scan it again, after you've added a new element?  An `Enumerator` that works that way *could* be written, I believe, but it would be very inefficient and messy and complicated.

Answer (score 2):

there are two things to notice here:

1. `elements()` creates the enumeration from properties. once it's created, it is disconnected from the properties itself. The meaning of that is that adding one more property afterwards will not be added to the enumeration
2. an enumeration is a 'one time' object, similar to iterator. This means you can loop over the elements one time, after that, the `hasMoreElements` will return false every time you call it.

given that two facts, it makes perfect sense the second print prints nothing

Comment: Are you sure #1 is right?  I looked at the code, and I don't see any evidence that the `Enumeration` is totally disconnected from the `Properties`.  In fact, I think the `Enumeration` shares a reference to the hash table with the `Properties`, which means that if you add to the `Properties`, the Enumeration *might* see it later--or it might not, depending on what hash bucket the new elements get added to.  I haven't tested this, however.  I don't think you can count on either behavior.

Comment: @ajb - I never looked at the code, but as you say- you cant count on it, I think its implementation dependant

Answer (score 2):

Do not forget to reset your enumeration before using it again.

```
eString1 = p1.elements();

while (eString1.hasMoreElements()) {
    System.out.println(eString1.nextElement());
}
```

Comment: That probably doesn't do what the OP was hoping for... I think he was hoping that after adding new elements, the `Enumerator` would print just the new ones.  If that's what he's looking for, however, it's impossible.